# Cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to instantiate an object then give all its children a script

```
     public void buildTownHall()
 {
     GameObject TownHallBuilding = Instantiate(townhall, pos, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)));

     foreach (Transform TownHallBuilding in transform)
     {
         TownHallBuilding.gameObject.AddComponent<ChangeColorChild>();
     }

     TownHallBuilding.AddComponent<ChangeColor>();
     TownHallBuilding.SetActive(true);
 }
```

But I keep getting the error message that's in the title.

Comment: You have `TownHallBuilding` as a `GameObject` and as a `Transform`.

Comment: @LarsTech what would I change, I would assume its this

        foreach (GameObject TownHallBuilding in transform)
        {
            TownHallBuilding.gameObject.AddComponent<ChangeColorChild>();
        }

But, it still has the same error

Comment: Message means exactly what it says. You can't declare two different things with the same name in the same scope. See duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

```
GameObject TownHallBuilding = Instantiate(... // TownHallBuilding #1
foreach (Transform TownHallBuilding in transform) // TownHallBuilding  #2
```

You cannot have both.

BTW. Local variables normally start with common letter (not capital).

Maybe the foreach is meant to be:

```
foreach (Transform t in transform)
{
   // Use t
}
```